# Term for when a reader strongly predicts an outcome simply because the story would seemingly fail if it went differently

Tags: phrase-requests, literary-techniques

When discussing, say, predictions for the ending of a novel, I've often heard logic along the lines of:

> This character *must* survive, because if (s)he doesn't, the story would be [depressing/underwhelming/meaningless/etc.].

Is there an English term for this? I was thinking it could be some form of prediction, expectation or perhaps "predestination", but I can't find a logical adjective to add to refer to this specific form. Note that I am not looking for a description of the validity of this technique, just the usage itself.

Comment: While I'm sure there's a word for something happening because it seemingly *must* happen (the first-person POV character not dying because they are the narrator of the story)—and even that isn't a certainty—I can think of no circumstance that would preclude a story from being depressing, meaningless, or anything else. Many stories are those things.

Comment: @JasonBassford Agreed. Nonetheless, I've heard the argument made... I think it comes down to the specific instance. The idea as I see it is that, for the particular story, it would seemingly destroy the point the author has been making, marginalize other portions of the work, or otherwise undermine the nature/course. The argument may not be valid, but it seems pretty common either way! I think it's more about personal feelings than reality. I'm trying to describe the argument independent of its legitimacy.

Comment: It sounds like wishful thinking to me . . . (Which isn't actually a logical argument at all—but more a fallacy of faith.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One phrase is **plot armor**. It means that a character of the story cannot possibly die. (E.g. the *Game of Thrones* had originally been praised for the lack of it.) It's an ever more established phrase.

> Look, plenty of people on the show right now, unfortunately, have "plot armor" and the days of "anyone can die" are gone. You could argue that Tormund, despite having fallen with the Wall, is alive because he needs to be with Brienne. You could also make the case that Gendry and Arya are safe because they need to wind up together too. And those are just love connections. It used to be that this show (because of the books, naturally) would kill you off regardless of what your predicted path might be. Now, things are bit more traditionally TV.
>
> By Matt Fowler
>
> http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/08/28/game-of-thrones-the-dragon-and-the-wolf-review

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plot%20armor) has this on the topic (entry from April 2008):

> **Character shields** (also known as **plot armor** or **plot shield**) are plot devices in films and television shows that prevent important characters from dying or being seriously injured at dramatically inconvenient moments. It often denotes a situation in which it strains credibility to believe that the character would survive.

Answer (score 1):

See ODOL.

[predictable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predictable)

> adjective
>   **1.1** *derogatory* Always behaving or occurring in the way expected.
>   ‘the characters are stereotyped and extremely predictable’

Need say more?

Comment: It's EOLD (English Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Which is EOLD? What has that got to do with me?

Comment: The link, what does the L stand for in ODOL? Oxford Dictionary Online ?? Learners?

Comment: end-of-life in dementia